# Rango de fechas

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un rango de fechas que va comprobando si las fechas ingresadas por un usuario coinciden con algun dia de oferta en la base de datos, al coincidir, imprime el nuevo precio, pero me da dos problemas:
1) si tengo mas de dos ofertas en la DB me imprime doble los precios y fechas
2) si una oferta está del 06-04-2018 hasta el 08-04-2018 me da el precio nuevo, pero me lo vuelve a dar el 06-05-2018 hasta el 06-05-2018

codigo del rango de fechas:

```
        $price = Data::PriceSearch("price_hdcd");

for($i=$dateinstr; $i<=$dateoutstr; $i = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i ."+ 1 days"))){ 
                    $UNIX = strtotime($i);
                    $STR = date("d-m-Y", $UNIX);
                      foreach ($price as $row => $priceout) {
                        if ($STR >= $priceout['dateini'] && $STR <= $priceout['datefin'] ) {
                              echo '
                                    <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">'.$STR.'</td>
                                    <td>'.$priceout['cd'].' &euro;</td>
                                    <td>'.$priceout['mp'].' &euro;</td>
                                    <tr>';
                        } else {
                          $totalcd = $PriceSystemArray['cd'];
                          $totalmp = $PriceSystemArray['mp'];
                              echo '
                                    <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">'.$STR.'</td>
                                    <td>'.$totalcd.' &euro;</td>
                                    <td>'.$totalmp.' &euro;</td>
                                    <tr>';
                            }

                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
```

codigo de la db:

```
public function PriceSearch($table){
        $stmt = Connection::Connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table");
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías mejorar tu consulta agregando condiciones y un límite:

```
SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $fechaUsuario BETWEEN dateini AND datefin LIMIT 1
```

Comment: en ese caso, tendría que pasar las fechas a la db en formato UNIX no?

Comment: Sería en formato año-mes-día

Comment: hey bro, lo hago como me dices pero la consulta no me devuelve nada, estoy urgido, llevo días tratando de hacer esta tarea y la tengo que entregar hoy a las 6:00

Comment: si la hago con fecha UNIX Funciona pero me imprime toda la tabla